# Return list function python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I'm trying this code below q Objects1 return to list

how can I do this?

it returns me the following error

File "/ home/paulo/Desktop/testepy2/objectMIB.py", line 53 
     return 
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

thank you

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp import debug
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context, ntforg
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.smi import builder

import threading
import collections
import time

MibObject = collections.namedtuple('MibObject', ['mibName',
                                   'objectType', 'valueFunc'])


class Mib(object):
    """Stores the data we want to serve. 
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.RLock()
        self._test_count = 0
    self._test_get = 10
    self._test_set = 0 

    def getTestDescription(self):
        return "My Description"

    def getTestCount(self):
        with self._lock:
            return self._test_count

    def setTestCount(self, value):

        with self._lock:
            self._test_count = value

    def getTestGet(self):
            return self._test_get

    def getTestSet(self):
            return self._test_set


    def setTestSet(self):
            self._test_set = value

class ListObejtc ():
    mib = objectMIB.Mib()
        objects1 = [MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testDescription', mib.getTestDescription),
               MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testCount', mib.getTestCount),MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testGet', mib.getTestGet), MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testSet', mib.getTestSet) ]

    print objects1
    return
```

Comment: You have added a `return` statement in a class context, which indeed is a SyntaxError. Also, pay attention to indentation, the code you posted has some indentation issues.

Comment: If you are new to python I want to give you a piece of advice: always read the error tracebacks, often it provides clear info on the error that you can use to solve it

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for the code you have shown nested inside "`ListObejtc`" to be in a method, like so:

```
class ListObejtc ():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def doObjects(self):
        mib = objectMIB.Mib()
        objects1 = [MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testDescription', mib.getTestDescription),
               MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testCount', mib.getTestCount),MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testGet', mib.getTestGet), MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testSet', mib.getTestSet) ]

        print objects1
        return objects1
```

You got a `SyntaxError` because the `return` as you had it was in class context, and it makes no sense there.

Comment: An `__init__()` method should do initializations, it shouldn't return anything.

Comment: There should not be a return statement in `__init__`

Comment: tsk, tsk.  pretty careless.  Corrected.

Comment: Thanks, but now it is returning the following error

Comment: File "/home/paulo/Desktop/testepy2/objectMIB.py", line 50
    pass
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Double-check that you have entered it correctly.  That `IndentationError` is probably because you haven't reproduced the code as shown.